# Controller doesn't update Razor view model: how to pass value to a view

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, .net-core, view, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to set up a simple web page build with Razor and .net Core.

My controller:

```
[HttpGet("/api/employees")]

public ActionResult Index()
{
    MyPaginationModel aux = new MyPaginationModel();
    aux.Employees = new List<EmployeeViewModel> {
    new EmployeeViewModel{
        Name = "Test",
        Surname = "Test",
        }
    };
    return View(aux);
}
```

my view:

```
@page


@model MyPaginationModel

<table class="table table-striped">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Employees)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Name</td>
            <td>@item.Surname</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

MyPaginationModel:

```
public class MyPaginationModel : PageModel
{
    public List<EmployeeViewModel> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

And EmployeeViewModel:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

It complaints about a nullreferencepointexception at Model.Employees . So, somehow I need to pass the instance I created in the controller to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `@page` directive makes the view into an MVC action.
It means that it handles requests directly, without going through a controller.

More info : [Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

**Solution:**

1. Remove : `@page`
2. Add : `@using MyPaginationModel Namespace`